# Connect to a database and exchange information with Windows apps and smartphones simultaneously

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, windows

I'm developing an application that will run on a couple computers and phones(android, iPhone, Windows phone) as a client and 1 computer act as the host for data and do some calculations all of this happening in the local network but I dont really know what's the best way to do this.

I'm thinking of something like a Windows service that will use a database for storage of variables settings for each user etc.

So my question is what should I use wcf, sqlserver or something else?

Comment: Can you clearly state your question?

Comment: My question is what should I use wcf, sqlserver or something else?